# How do I play the "Cradle of Civilization" DLC?

Tags: civilization-5

I own several of the "Cradle of Civilization" DLC packs for Civ 5, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to load them.  It's not an option under "scenarios," and when I set up a game, it's not an option under map type either.

I've double checked the store page and the Downloadable Content dialog in Steam, and both confirm that I own the pack.

> The Cradle of Civilization map packs are Firaxis-designed maps of real-world locations. You can play random leaders in these settings, or choose leaders appropriate to the history of these areas. The maps can also be opened up in World Builder, where you can even create specific scenarios.

How do I play a game with this DLC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are only maps (not scenarios), the pack includes map types called `Americas, Asia, Mediterranean and Mesopotamia`.

The answer is that they will appear for you via the following menu path:

```
/Mods/Single Player/Setup Game/{Map Type}
```

They **should** appear in the regular single player setup. It is a poor mistake by the game makers.

*I always use the mod route to setup a game. I no longer use the Single Player option at the start.*
*(Tip: setup your defaults via regular single player, start tha game. As soon as you see your settler, exit and go to the Mod setup game to see the default selections saved)*

Here is a print screen showing Americas and Asia.
[image]

My last game was on the Bering Strait which was awesome. However, I am not sure if it came from another map pack or was with the game to begin with.