# Where oh where is my scenario menu?

Tags: civilization-5

I've downloaded and reinstalled the Steam version of Civilization (version 1.0.1.511 on Windows 7) along with all of its DLCs: everything is marked as "Installed" and the custom maps are all there and working. The game runs fine as well.

However, neither the main menu nor any of the sub-menus have the "Scenarios" menu. I've searched everywhere with no luck, and I have no way of accessing any of the DLC content.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you're talking about the Cradle of Civilization "scenarios" you may be interested in: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58278/how-do-i-play-the-cradle-of-civilization-dlc

Comment: thx but the issue is that I the actual menu to get to the scenarios doesnt exist.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you see after clicking Single Player on the main menu?

Comment: Umm dont think this site supports me uploading images.

Comment: Menus after clicking "single player": Play Now, Set Up Game, Load Game, Tutorial... and Back

Comment: There's an image button that should be right above your question text when you are editing.  If you go to the Mods menu and select Browse Mods, do you see the scenarios listed there?  For example, I see a listing for the Genghis Khan scenario there.

Comment: Hmm I'll check.

Comment: No, I don't see any listing for genghis.

Comment: Just all the mods i've downloaded. I'm talking about DLC packs. I bought like 40$ worth of them today :) cant play any of them

Comment: @Tabwood: I'd suggest checking the install on steam. To do this, right click on the game in your steam library, select Properties, select the "Local Files" tab then "Verify Integrity of Game Cache"

Comment: @TZHX: Hilarious. That fixed it. There was 1 file that couldnt be validated. Steam fixed it and then I booted up and the scenario menu suddenly appeared.

Comment: @Tabwood I don't see the hilarity, but glad it's working for you.

Comment: @Tabwood: You should delete this question as you solved your issue, there are no answers and it is too localized.

Comment: Voted to close Being too localized.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [verifying integrity](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335)?

### Verify integrity of game cache

1. Load Steam
2. From the Library section, right-click on the game and select
   Properties from the menu.
3. Select the Local files tab and click the Verify integrity of game
   cache... button.
4. Steam will verify the game's files - this process may take several
   minutes.
5. Once the process is completed, the Check Window will automatically
   exit.

Comment: If you had read the comments this was answered over a month ago. Youve brought up an old post :O

Comment: @Doomsknight Comments are not answers: if someone leaves a comment that solves a problem, it's [totally fair game](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78036/149432) to move it to the answer section so it's not buried.

Comment: fair enough :).